Does anyone know how to identify a composite deck board by serial number on the board?
I am working on a deck from 2007. The builder told the homeowner he was installing Trex. The boards warped and became uneven and are stained. I sent pictures to Trex and they deny the boards are theirs. Is there any possibility that someone could help me to positively identify the composite deck boards used? Writing on the side starts with 4 skewed letters that appear to be COMC and then are followed by the following strain of letters and numbers 1325-R BAM AM21407245

The deck was built 17 years ago. If you do find out what the manufacturer of the decking was or is, how will this affect your course of repair? The likelihood of getting any type of warranty action is very slim.

Have you searched the internet for those series of number?
